# Input after text heading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an input right after a text ends. (Not after the div that contains the text).

Something like this:
[image: example]

But I don't know how to do it.
I tried to place it with an absolute position but when I resize the window it overlaps the text and input.

This is my css:

```
  .div-heading {
      position: relative;
    }

  .heading-2 {
    font-size: 52px;
  }
    
  .search{
      position: absolute;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      margin-top: -89px;
      margin-left: 239px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have not explained `how` you are trying to do this - with CSS presumably? Please add the HTML and the css you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it through `display: inline`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space:normal;
}
label, input {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
 <div>
    <label for="spd">VERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERYERYVERYVERYVERYVERYVERY</label> <input type="text" name="spd" id="spd" />
  </div>
```